# How to use exclamation marks in commandline as part of String?

Tags: string, hadoop

I would like to execute some Hadoop  map reduce job with string search function.

The command looks like:

```
hadoop search "asdcg!sfdf"
```

Then it will show

`zsh: event not found:sfdf`

I tried to replace "!" with "^!" or "^^!", and still have same outcome.

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape characters like `!` using single quotes:

```
hadoop search 'asdcg!sfdf'
```